# MVC 5 Ajax.Begin form doesn't replace UpdateTargetId

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working at website and i want to add comments to a post, everything is working with Html.Begin form but the page is refreshing everytime i add a comment.

I replaced the Html.BeginForm with Ajax.BeginForm but i hav to refresh the page in order to see the comment.
I added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js but still not working.

Controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult Comments(string id)
    {
        return PartialView("Comments", _dc.Comments.Where(m => m.Id_P == id).OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult AddComment(string id, string comment)
    {
        Comment com = new Comment();
        com.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        com.Id_A = AccountInfo.Id;
        com.CommentT = comment;
        com.Id_P = id;   
        com.Date = String.Format("{0: dd MMM 'at' HH:mm}", DateTime.Now);

        _dc.Comments.Add(com);
        _dc.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="article-comments">
    <div class="post-comm">
        @Html.Action("Comments", "Post", new { id = item.Id })
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", "Post", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "post-comm" }))
            {
                <input type="hidden" id="id" value="@item.Id" name="id" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="enter your comment..." name="comment" id="comment">
                    </div>
                </div>
             }
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this but now is refreshing the page

```
public JsonResult AddComment(string id, string comment)
    {
        Comment com = new Comment();
        com.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        com.Id_A = AccountInfo.Id;
        com.CommentT = comment;
        com.Id_P = id;   
        com.Date = String.Format("{0: dd MMM 'at' HH:mm}", DateTime.Now);

        _dc.Comments.Add(com);
        _dc.SaveChanges();

        return Json("success");
    }
```

The view:

```
<div class="post-comm">
    @Html.Action("Comments", "Post", new { id = item.Id })
</div>
<form method="post" onsubmit="addComment('@item.Id', this)">
    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="enter your comment..." name="comment" id="comment">
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

And the ajax call

```
function addComment(idP, el) {
var comm = $(el).find("#comment").val()
$.ajax({
    url: "/Post/AddComment/",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id: idP, comment: comm },
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        $(".post-comm").load("@Html.Action('Comments', 'Post', new { id = "+ idP +"})")
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("error - comment post");
    }
});}
```

Comment: do you get an error or it just refreshes? and don't you think it would be easier if you just make a jquery.ajax call to your controller and return partial view containing your newly added comment?
and redirecttoaction in the last line seems like the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't have RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); in an Ajax method

Comment: Your making an ajax call but attempt to redirect in the POST method (ajax calls never redirect). You need to return a partial view (and why are you replacing the whole form anyway)

Comment: What should i return then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i finnaly did it.
I did it like Burak said and is working.

i made an ajax call to return the partial view like this:

```
function reloadComments(el) {
var idP = $(el).attr("id")
$.ajax({
    url: '/Post/Comments/',
    data: { id: idP, },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        $(el).prevAll("div.post-comm:first").html(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("error - load comments");
    }
});}
```

and the view:

```
<div class="post-comm">
    @Html.Action("Comments", "Post", new { id = item.Id })
</div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", "Post", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "reloadComments(this)" }, new { id=item.Id}))
{
     <input type="hidden" id="id" value="@item.Id" name="id" />
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="enter your comment..." name="comment" id="comment">
         </div>
     </div>
}
```

The controller is like the last one from my question.
I hope this help someone